# Accessing inside an array

Tags: java, angularjs, json, loops

I want to know how to access value inside an array controlVal. Basically when user select's option form controlVal array i am checking it with new and old value so that i can disable enable submit button.

This is my condition

```
else if(JSON.parse(newValue.CONTROLID1).controlVal !=
        JSON.parse(oldValue.CONTROLID1).controlVal
                  ||
        JSON.parse(newValue.CONTROLID2).controlVal != 
        JSON.parse(oldValue.CONTROLID2).controlVal)
```

This is link to an image depicting array.
http://tinypic.com/r/f2iulg/9

Comment: Someone plz answer it! need it asap

Comment: To access the array you need to index the particular position.something like else if(control[JSON.parse(newValue.CONTROLID1)]!=control[JSON.parse(newValue.CONTROLID1)]||control[JSON.parse(newValue.CONTROLID1)]!=control[JSON.parse(newValue.CONTROLID2)])

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the index of the item you want referenced.

```
else if(JSON.parse(newValue.CONTORLID1).controlVal[index] != JSON.parse(oldValue.CONTROLID1).controlVal[index] ||  JSON.parse(newValue.CONTROLID2).controlVal[index] != 
    JSON.parse(oldValue.CONTROLID2).controlVal[index]){
// Do something here
}
```

Just substitute index for the actually array index (an integer) you want to access.

Comment: i can't substitute index for an integer, i don't have to access value only at a particular index instead i want it to be accessed dynamically inside a watch function which cover all instances of new and old controlVal

Comment: So you want to compare the whole array and not just access a single value, correct?

Comment: when user selects a value then it gets substituted to newValue and when user selects another value then previously selected value gets substituted to oldValue.Then these two values needs to be compared

Comment: In that case I would use an ArrayList<> instead of an array.

Comment: Can't use  arraylist now...it  will be tedious now! any other way to get out of above problem

Comment: Yes, you can still use an array. You will just need to reference the index in the array for the variable you want to replace. `String[] hello = {"Hello", "World"};
        hello[0] = "Apple";` returns an array of [Apple, World]